# How to change the Working Directory in Xcode 11.4.1

Tags: xcode

It used to be: Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme

It's gone. I searched online, no one seems to mention this. I searched the help on Xcode, nothing. Any help is much appreciated.

In Xcode 11.4.1, it now looks like this: [image]

Comment: Is it a Mac project or iOS project? Only Mac projects let you change the working directory. On Xcode 11.4.1,  I see a checkbox to use a custom working directory in the Options section for a Cocoa project.

Comment: It is an iOS project...I see the problem haha

Answer (score 0):

Custom working directory only available for Mac Projects, not iOS projects. Credit to @Mark Szymczyk